# Doctrine Criteria class: use comparing methods to compare 2 fields

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2.7.1 inside Symfony 5.1.11. To query repositories often I use the Criteria class that is very flexible and in most of cases saves me to write queryBuider instructions.

The question is: is it possible to use Criteria comparative methods to check between two fields?

Normally comparative methods needs a value as second parameter

```
Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->gt("field1", 100));
```

What I sometimes need is something like

```
Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->gt("field1", "field2"));
```

Thanks